# ImageView leaves a lot of free space

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I need to make a table with pictures. So I decided to do it with TableLayout (instead of TableRow i used LinearLayout cause of weightSum).
There is a code:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/card_shirt"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/card_shirt"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/card_shirt"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/card_shirt"
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/card_shirt"
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/card_shirt"
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</TableLayout>
```

It's not a whole code, in my app i do it dynamically, but it doesn't change the essense.

So the issue is on a picture below:

[image]

What is the free space above and below each picture? How can i get rid of it?

Comment: Maybe you should consider using GridView instead of this dynamic TableLayout/LinearLayout/ImageView thing.

Comment: You want your image to full screen(height) right?

Comment: @Amsheer I want to occupy the entire width with my images proportionally and height must be chosen so that image changed in propotion to the width. But this free spaces disappointing me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happen because of ImageView auto detect the width and height of real image

However , the width is not enough, so the ImageView auto resize the image to fit for it's width

and that's why their height is still there, and display as free space as you mention

**How to solve**

make sure you add

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

in ImageView

or just clicked at this checkbox

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also to set

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```